# How to format a table to include outline around bars

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I am trying to format a table in R Shiny and the bars are coming out fine, they just do not have any white space (or outline) in between the rows.  My code is as follows:

```
formatStyle('score', background = styleColorBar(real$score, 
'lightblue'),
 backgroundSize = '100% 50%',
 backgoundRepeat = 'no-repeat',
backgroundPosition = 'center')
```

[image]

What I am looking for is something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Author X. Person"
date: "October 11, 2018"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r tabsets, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
library(DT)
library(data.table)

d = data.table(x = 1:10,time = as.POSIXct('2018-10-11 12:00:00.123'))
d$score <- seq(1,10,1)

datatable(d, options=list(
 initComplete = JS("
    function(settings, json) {
      $(this.api().table().td()).css({
        'border-collapse': 'collapse',
        'border-bottom-width': '4px',   
        'background-color': '#000',
        'color': '#eee'
      });
    }"),
        pageLength = 10,
        lengthMenu = c(2, 12, 18),
        searching= FALSE)) %>% 
formatStyle('score', background = styleColorBar(d$score, 'lightblue'),
        backgroundSize = '100% 50%',
        backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat',
        backgroundPosition = 'center')
```
````

It results in this:

[image]